# ELCImagePickerController not scrolling

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone sdk. I have taken ELCImagePickerController. When i am scrolling library ,it is crashing and giving me as reason :`GuardMalloc[Traveler's Note-2211]: Failed to VM allocate 16 bytes
GuardMalloc[Traveler's Note-2211]: Explicitly trapping into debugger!!!
GuardMalloc[Traveler's Note-2211]: Failed to VM allocate 112 bytes
GuardMalloc[Traveler's Note-2211]: Explicitly trapping into debugger!!!`

Please help me. Thanking You...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are running out of memory. Because your log is saying like VM is unable to allocate X bytes of memory.

Here is a link that will exactly help you in your issue.

[Help link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829808/ios-bad-access-impossible-to-find)

Do you have a didReceiveMemoryWarning method implemented? If so, put a NSLog in it to find out if you are lowon memory.