# UICollectionView - GuardMalloc : Failed to VM allocate 65536 bytes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

When I'm running and using my app in debug mode with NSZombie and Guard Malloc enable, I end up with the following error:

```
GuardMalloc[MyApp-7710]: Failed to VM allocate 65536 bytes
GuardMalloc[MyApp-7710]: Explicitly trapping into debugger!!!
```

Just before I get this error, my app start lagging a lot. However, when I perform the same test case without debug mode, my app is very smooth and there's no lag. I also checked with Instruments, it appears that there's no leak.

What is the meaning of this message? How to fix it?

-- EDIT --

The error is always triggered from a layout of one of my `UICollectionView`. Here is the code of the function that triggers the error:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
   attributes.frame = CGRectMake(10 * indexPath.row, 10 * indexPath.section, 10, 10);
   return attributes;
}
```

The error occurs on the first line of this function

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS bad access impossible to find](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829808/ios-bad-access-impossible-to-find)

Comment: I saw this thread before, but it did not really help me